# Babel command line all jsx files in a directory, output as js files

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have been running a command to turn .jsx files into .js files one at a time:

```
npx babel App.jsx --out-file App.js --plugins=@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

I want to do it for everything in a directory. I read through the help command's options and it seems like I should be able to do this

```
npx babel -d mydirectory -x .jsx  --plugins=@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

But that says it requires filenames, despite providing a directory.

What's the right syntax to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to babel docs, it appears the syntax is

```
npx babel mydirectory --out-dir dist -x .jsx  --plugins=@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#compile-directories